# Shapefile is not shown on a raster image although having same CRS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have a shapefile which was digitized from a jpg map. the only info i knew from that jpg, the map was created in lambert conformal conic(north).
so, i have digitize and create my shapefile with the same CRS. 
now i want to check my shapefile by overlapping on a landsat image which is in EPSG: 32645 WGS 84/ UTM ZONE 45. 
i have changed my shapefile´s CRS into EPSG: 32645 WGS 84/ UTM ZONE 45 but still the shapefile is not shown on the exact location. 
what can I do now?

Comment: did you *set* the CRS or *reprojected* it? what software are you using?

Comment: You need much more info than Lambert Conformal Conic to specify an input projection.. Did you project your data or re-assert to WGS84 UTM Zone 45 North? How *exactly* did you change your CRS?

Comment: ThingumaBob, I am using QGIS. I have tried both ways, by changing layer CRS and using reproject layer. the CRS changes but the coordinate points do not overlap with the Landsat image.

Comment: Michael, I only have the info about Lambert conformal conic from the website which provides the pdf map.the name is http://gis.lged.gov.bd/Map/Public/published-map and my district was "pabna" upazilla 'sujanagar'. when i move mouse on the map it shows coordinates in meter, but when export the map in pdf, it said the map is producd by LCC. I am using QGIS.